# Prevent closing sub menu on page changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I write this function for open and close sub menu and it works fine but I have this problem:
If user click a submenu item and open the page(this menu is in master page) the submenu doesnt close. How can I do that??

[fiddler Link (more clear with css)](http://jsfiddle.net/WmRuN/306/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.has-sub > a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var submenu = $(this).next();
        if (submenu.is(":visible")) {
            submenu.slideUp();
            $(this).closest("li").removeClass("active");
        }
        else {
            submenu.slideDown();
            $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
        }
    });
    });

    ///my html menu it is in my masterpage(i use mvc4 razor)

   <div id='cssmenu'>
   <ul>
       <li class="has-sub"><a href='#'><span>submenu</span></a>
        <ul class="subbg">
          <li><a href="#"><span>aaaa</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>bbbb</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>cccc</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>ddddd</span></a></li>  
        </ul>
           </li> 
       <li><a href="#"><span>wwww</span></a></li>
       </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused: you either want to "prevent closing", or you want it to close: "the submenu doesn't close. how can i do that??". Which one?

Comment: the items under submenu will close after page changing.i want prevent that

Comment: I add fiddler link it is more cleare

Comment: if you are using absolute links you could just cycle through each of the `a` tags in `#cssmenu` looking for where `document.URL == a.attributes.href` and then apply the `active` class to the nearest `has-sub` element.. else you could find replace the base domain from `document.URL` to compare if you're using relative links